# Return Array of SUMPRODUCT Results

Tags: excel, vlookup, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to merge the contents of tables, rank them, and return the results as an array so that, eventually, values can be found with `INDEX` or `VLOOKUP`. I'm on a work network. I am stuck with Excel 2013 without PowerQuery and macros are a hard no. I am trying to avoid hidden sheets and helper columns. I have managed to successfully combine the output of tables into a single array, but am having trouble accomplishing getting a ranking of each item into an array.

Here is the sample workbook I'm using to do a proof of concept:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmnV99KYATO-g5kxvJBpTSSjF_XBXw

Everything is currently on just one sheet, but the goal is to eventually link tables from multiple sheets or even workbooks together and have the results automatically aggregated in a table that is both sortable and filterable. I'm trying to end the endless `Ctrl+C` and `Ctrl+V` I currently do to aggregate data.

For readability, most of the formulas in the workbook have been turned into named arrays. I have the last few steps broken out so you can see where I am stuck. The components of the named array `RANKED` only return a single digit, not an array of 24 values like the `COMBINED` formula. When I `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` my final `RANKED` array I get the expected result, but when I do `VLOOKUP` and `INDEX` I get errors because `RANK` only returns one value. You can see in the table on the right `VLOOKUP` fails after the first row.

I am using `SUMPRODUCT` instead of `COUNTIF` because (as far as I know) `COUNTIF` cannot take arrays as input. There is then an offset so that the ranking works like `RANK.EQ`. Does anyone know how to accomplish what I am trying to do or am I attempting the impossible?

Comment: On your link, I can see the excel but cannot see the formulaes in each cell. The formula bar is missing for some reason!

Comment: It's OneDrive so the file needs to be downloaded. Three dots in the upper right next to Share, then hit download. Thanks for taking the time to look... this is driving me bonkers.

Comment: I am soooooo close. I have everything except the array offset working so that it works like RANK.EQ.